# How to gzip compress Symfony4 http response before sending it?

Tags: symfony4, http-compression

I am developing a site with Symfony 4. After a test with GTmetrix, it appears that the files sent by the site are not compressed.

At the beginning I thought it should be a process made by the web server by default but after having contacted the hosting provider, they said it should be done by the code itself.

Do you have any idea of how it should be done with Symfony 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gzip compression is done directly by the server :

Here there are websites where you can see how to do it depending on what server you use, Apache or nginx :

**Apache**: https://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/how-enable-gzip-compression-apache

**Nginx**: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-the-gzip-module-to-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: With this links, I had contact the second level support, they asked me to put this code in the `.htaccess`

`<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>`